# How does a plain infer statement alter a type

Tags: typescript

Is there a concrete explanation to what the following type does?

```
type I<T> = T extends infer V ? V : never;
```

Or is the effect this may have dependant on the context within which it is used.

From where I have used it, seems it affects how types are resolved. For example, given a type `T`, using `I<T>` instead of `T` directly solves `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite` in the context of where it was used. But the type `I` here in theory looks to me like it would do almost nothing.

I appreciate this is a fairly general question, but that's really the type definition I would like to understand. If there is no straight forward answer to that I can create a simple example with some context that may highlight something more tangible, like maybe the possibly infinite recursion story.

Here is an example to demonstrate, it's a bit longer than I would have liked but I think this is close to the minimal amount to reproduce.

Starts with a type `Target` that could be a `string`, `number` or array of `Target`.

```
type Primitive = string | number;
type ArrayTarget = readonly Target[];
type Target = Primitive | ArrayTarget;
```

And the following `Action` and `Delta` types. Action could have been just `update` but was important that this was a mapped object to demonstrate.

```
type ActionName = "update" | "add" | "remove";

type Action<V extends Target, A extends ActionName = ActionName> = {
  update: ["update", number, Delta<V>];
  add: ["add", number, V];
  remove: ["remove", number];
}[A];

export type Delta<T extends Target> = T extends Primitive
  ? T
  : T extends readonly (infer V extends Target)[]
  ? Action<V>
  : never;
```

Basically for `T`, `Delta<T>` should return `T` for a `Primitive` `T` type and an `Action` type for an array, that defines applicable operations on an array.

Now if we want a type to represent a `Target` together with its corresponding `Delta`, we have the following payload type.

```
type Payload<T extends Target> = readonly [T, Delta<T>];
```

Again it seemed important this was a tuple to demonstrate the case.

If we want to narrow this with a type guard to check if it is `Primitive`.

```
const isPrimitivePayload = <T extends Target>(
  payload: Payload<T>
): payload is Payload<T & Primitive> => true;
```

We get `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)`
on the predicate return type.

If instead we repeat the above but using the infer type `I` to define the Delta for a primitive, there is no error.

```
type I<T extends Primitive> = T extends infer V ? V : never;

type DeltaPrimitiveInfer<T extends Target> = T extends Primitive
  ? I<T>
  : T extends readonly (infer V extends Target)[]
  ? Action<V>
  : never;

type PayloadWithInfer<T extends Target> = readonly [T, DeltaPrimitiveInfer<T>];

const isPrimitivePayloadInferType = <T extends Target>(
  payload: PayloadWithInfer<T>
): payload is PayloadWithInfer<T & Primitive> => true; // all good
```

Here's a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=35&ssc=80&pln=27&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI4BuAKFEigEE44BDEAFR5xiEYFBxwIPACYB7QgBsQUQcNEBtALos20VSLE54yVBmgUuvAUIMtW4aBwDGaeQDkeSbFABEVMNI8wBA+5L4y0qEUPpJIspg+drqcLgjyADwAalAQAB7BhNK4KjaiADScOfkQhcXOroQeXuIpDU0QAHwtAN7MUFD+gcEAXFDqfgFBIRXUdAwVACIQCsA8WR3afVARo+MRPjM09HAVmZv9sfEQuzEQcQmHc3CbAL7qHJvMeWCycGLJSxWa34VQKRRKamAXRwILyYOKxhQaEwWwA-CotqNYdValBJDJ5EooAAKBCEABmDCg2ThNXB+lEAEotGjWmlCOtMZQIJgmMx7OwYHwFLIZOlsfCIQZoXipHJFMp1PxFstVuKNnYnPJ8FAELhEaZMEKQCKZC1xaC6cUGVDiVswMLRdJRsbTdJ1cxGaMHSanbqEY6xSCAGSwRBIszQroEKgQRhQAD0CZUDl1hHwPEIaCC7P9VScEFwuDMROkEAgYG2hSgPyLCFoRLJ5LJqAgADpiQAmACsAA4AJyM-lJqAAWnHE8nU+nM9nc-nM+YI6oxZIUAAkhSqfIwyZkdBdLgBdB1xbabiDfuZRKrWnKXBqVB0dlRoQeQwkqnAatL2ZN-ezxxelSihFobwvcNDQgVlT34DouXA8F8XlIlSS3B8aSA60QOZTRWXqdlOX6V93z5Y9YEDaQAHVUAAC3-BhAMlG0ZWQwlFWVKBvx4X9MAYuB1U+LV0zEPVeIgV0nX4-hUxwJjbxYu1+h9N0XUomjgHo9CPS9GtKLzSSZA0rSAJDXcI0wKMoBjONE2THgFAUKBiFkWRpH5IA) to the code for this example.

Thanks

Comment: The type `I<T>` evaluates to `T` when `T` is some specific type, but evaluation of generic conditional types tend to be deferred, so it can definitely change the order of operations in the compiler enough to forestall circularity warnings.  But without a [mre] it's hard to say directly.  I could write that comment as an answer, but have no way to demonstrate anything without making wild guesses about relevant examples... if you could provide such examples it would be helpful

Comment: Thanks, yea sounds good. Think the deferred evaluation answers it but I'll update the question with an example so there's something concrete to refer to in the answer.

Comment: Added an example but can see if I just copy paste and rename the problematic function there is no error, so not so confident its a good example. Seems hard to reliably reproduce these recursion type erros.

Comment: It does look like `I<T>` is deferring evaluation enough to prevent the circularity warning there.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The utility type

```
type I<T> = T extends infer V ? V : never;
```

is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  It splits the input `T` into any [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members, performs the operation on each member separately, and joins the results back up into a union.   But since "the operation" here is just to copy each union member `T` into a new type parameter `V`, the whole thing acts as an *[identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) type function*.

So `I<T>` does indeed always evaluate to its input for any *specific* type argument passed for the type parameter `T`.  So `I<string>` is `string`, `I<Date>` is `Date`, `I<{ a: number } | undefined | Set<boolean> | (() => string)>` is `{ a: number } | undefined | Set<boolean> | (() => string)`, et cetera.

But things are more complicated when the type argument is a *generic* type, like `<X>(x: X) => () => I<X>` or `type G<X> = Array<I<X>>`.  [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `I<T>` (especially those using `infer`) are generally not *resolved* if they depend on generic type parameters.  Instead they are *deferred*, which means that in some sense they remain unevaluated and opaque. (See [microsoft/TypeScript#21316](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and [microsoft/TypeScript#21496](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496).)  Once the generic types are themselves specified, such deferred conditional types will be resolved, and `I<T>` will be resolved to whatever specific type ends up being specified for `T`.

So while there isn't really a semantic difference between `I<T>` and `T`, there could be a logistic difference.  The order of operations for type evaluation can be different.

---

If using `T` causes a circularity warning because the compiler eagerly resolves it and sees that it depends on itself in an illegal or problematic way, then replacing it with `I<T>` could possibly prevent that, since the compiler defers the evaluation instead.  For example:

```
// from
type TupleLen<N extends number, V = any, A extends V[] = []> =
  N extends A['length'] ? A : TupleLen<N, V, [V, ...A]>;

function repeat<N extends number, V>(n: N, v: V) {
  return Array.from({ length: n }, () => v) as TupleLen<N, V>; // error! type instantiation issue
}

// to
type TupleLen<N extends number, V = any, A extends V[] = []> =
  I<N> extends A['length'] ? A : TupleLen<N, V, [V, ...A]>;

function repeat<N extends number, V>(n: N, v: V) {
  return Array.from({ length: n }, () => v) as TupleLen<N, V>; // okay
}
```

Note that it's not *guaranteed* that `I<T>` will resolve circularity warnings; there's a lot involved in type evaluation, and sometimes the compiler might still see circularity even in the face of such tricks.  Conversely, it might be more worthwhile trying to understand why the original circularity warning was present and resolve it in a more decisive way:

```
type TupleLen<N extends number, V = any, A extends V[] = []> =
  A['length'] extends N ? A : TupleLen<N, V, [V, ...A]>;
```

The original problem with `TupLen` happens because `N` is constrained to `number`, but when `N` is *specified* as `number`, the type is circular... `N extends A['length']` is never true, and the compiler tries to compute an infinite tuple.  The fix with `I<N>` just sidestepped it; but if you accidentally compute `TupLen<number>` you'd hit the same problem.  Instead, `A['length'] extends N` will always be true if `N` is `number`, and you end up with a more stable type (although it too has failure modes, such as `N` being a negative or fractional number, and workarounds to deal with that are out of scope here).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgPAFQHxQLxQVCAPYEB2AJgM5QCW+AZhAE5QBqUA-A1AFxT4QButA3ACgBoSFADKaWHGLAaFAOZJBAemVR1APSbDw0ACKT4egIZ4lA1eqhadogKqG4AbyjGO+AK4BbAEa0oAL5QAD5QHkQQlBQQhCHiEMBwPgD2yQA2EMb4KKEAFLkAlGgoMnL48gXmlpraQiLQAGKScAAaSLnYHC1FqCiFxVJtgvVQAOKtKOgAgjQ0xiBw8G3mttAIHmAZADIEcAByWLgEJJzefjQANKzoWSBXU4d4RKT0ANoAupIfkwLqU68Acgy5WAAAsAZ8cE8TgcWA8OOtNhAdvh9ld6FdXhioAA6PFTd5VNRSPYoKHHUj-IEEeRgiHMKDwjAbba7PbozHYvE4gkrSjhADGwDIyXwUBoEEgpn2jwpp18tHR7XwHHZUG4HHoRScv3FCQ8NDFMzmIBxlBoyS8uRcwNpoPcgSu-V66qKxlIiNZqLV9CUUAEASEAtFMnVkglUuAuQAzFcAETGOMFFRqYP4UMaqCvUoKK458p52QKT7+gRp0MAd3DksyUYAjAAGK6eNJpZMWVMh4BQCscV4ttLNjytocj05jgejwfj6eTmdT95CIA)

Comment: thanks, nice explanation. And nice advice about rewriting the type to straight up avoid the recursion problem.